# sum of multiplication of two binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Is there any formula for calculating
$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} {2n\choose 2k}$ ?

One possible way is to use Stirling's approximation, but couldn't reach a reasonable answer.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Didn't get your meaning. Can you be more specific?

Comment: $$(1+x^2)^n(x+1)^{2n}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(x^2)^k\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}k x^{2n-k}$$

Compare the coefficients of $x^{2n}$

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not the most pleasant result.
$$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} {2n\choose 2k}=\, _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2}-n,-n,-n;\frac{1}{2},1;-1\right)$$ where appears the generalized hypergeometric function.

However, plotting $\log(S_n)$ as a function of $n$ reveals almost a straight line and a simple linear regression gives $$\log(S_n)\approx 2.06597 n-2.27715$$ ($R^2=0.999998$) which gives at least the order of magnitude.